# How to find the difference for an infinite fraction

Tags: binary, floating-point, rounding-error

Suppose I have the number `0.101` in binary. If I want to round it to 2 places after the radix point using the algorithm *rounding to the nearest* I can easily find the difference between two available options (`0.10` and `0.11`):

```
0.101 - 0.10 =  0.001 = 1/8
0.101 - 0.11 = -0.001 = -1/8
```

However, how I would do the subtraction for the infinite fraction like `0.1`:

$$ 0.1_{10} = 0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011..._2 $$

Suppose, I want to round it to 10 places after the radix point. How would I go about that?

Comment: Ten places takes you to $0.0001100110$ the next few digits are $011$. So if you round to the nearest you round down in this case. If the next few digits begin with a 0 you will always round down. If the next few digits begin with 11 you will always round up. You will also round up if the next digit is 1 and at some point there is a subsequent 1, eg 10000000001. The only tie-breaker case is 1000... .

Comment: Thanks, but how did you calculate that? To get the same result I'd need to do subtraction

Comment: Doing a subtraction is a huge waste of time. What is the tie breaker case where the number is exactly halfway between the two rounding possibilities? Answer it is the smaller one followed by a single 1. If there is any 1 after that, then it must be closer to the larger number. If the first digit is a 0, then we always round down (except in the case where that is followed by nothing but 1s, since that is another way of writing a 1 followed by 0s) because the smaller number must be closer.

Comment: Okay, let me digest it and I'll get back to you with questions. Maybe you could post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much quicker way of applying the "round to the nearest" rule than by carrying out subtractions.

Suppose rounding down gives $a$ and rounding up gives $b$. The "round to the nearest" rule says round to whichever of $a,b$ is nearer. That is unambiguous unless the number is $\frac{a+b}{2}$ which is equidistant. We deal with that case by a tie-breaker rule (which you asked about in an earlier question).

But another way of expressing the rule is that we round up if the number is $>\frac{a+b}{2}$ and round down if it is $<\frac{a+b}{2}$.

In the case of binary fractions the number $\frac{a+b}{2}$ is the smaller number $a$ followed by a digit 1 (and nothing or only 0s thereafter). So this alternative method is much quicker. If the next digit is a 1 and there is at some point a subsequent 1, then we round up, because the number must be closer to $b$. Similarly, if the next digit is a 0 and that is not followed by an infinite string of nothing but 1s, then we round down, because the number must be closer to $a$.

You asked in the comments below for an example. For example, suppose you want to round $x=0.0110110$ to 6 places. Your choices are $a=0.011011$ or $b=0.011100$. The midpoint is $\frac{a+b}{2}=0.0110111$ which can be obtained by adding a 1 at the end of $a$. In this case $x$ has a $0$ at the end so you round it down to $a$ because we have $x<\frac{a+b}{2}$.

Comment: can you please elaborate on this _In the case of binary fractions the number `(a+b)/2` is the smaller number `a` followed by a digit 1 (and nothing or only 0s thereafter)._ ? I think some example would be very helpful. thanks

Comment: thanks for you edition, but  I still have a lot of questions :(, bear with me please) I don't really understand how you came up with the `b` version `0.011100`? I thought it should be `0.011010`

Comment: If you *truncate* $x$ at 6 places you get $0.011011$. Rounding up means increasing the last digit by 1. That gives $0.011012$. But digits have to be 1 or 2, so we rewrite that as $0.01110$. Or more formally $0.011011+0.000001=0.011100$.

Comment: thanks a lot, I understand that the `a` (smaller) number will always be just truncated number?

Comment: @Maximus Yes, that is correct.

Comment: _In this case `x` has a `0` at the end so you round it down to `a` because_ - do you compare `x (0.0110110) < (a+b)/2 (0.0110111)`? 
But here you have `x` which is finite, in my example x is infinite. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, your $x=0.00011001100110\dots$ was infinite. But you wanted to round it to 10 places. Truncating to 10 places gives $a=0.0001100110$. So your answer will be either $a$ or $b=0.0001100111$. You see that the 11th digit of $x$ is $0$, so you round down to $a$.

Comment: Great, much appreciate. Now the last question... I can't seem to comprehend how this _11th digit of `x` is `0`, so you round down to `a`_ replaces comparison of `x` and `(a+b)/2`. Can you please explain that too?

Comment: The basic idea is that instead of doing any subtractions or comparisons you just inspect the following digit. The material about $\frac{a+b}{2}$ is just to explain why that works. If the following digit is a 0, you round down (leaving aside the extremely unusual case of it being followed by an infinite number of 1s and no 0s). If the following digit is a 1, you round up. If you want a tie-breaker rule other than "round up" then you need to check if the 1 is followed by all 0s. If it is, apply your tie-breaker rule.

Comment: Very much appreciate your help! I'll think though it later. I've asked [another](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1791562/converting-0-1-to-double) question, if you'll have some time, take a look please.