# Converting 0.1 to binary 64 bit double

Tags: binary, floating-point

I want to convert the decimal number 0.1 to binary 64 bit double. So I do it like that:

$$ 0.1_{10} = 0.00011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110... \times 2^0 $$

Represent it in the scientific form:

$$ 1.1001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110... \times 2^{-4} $$

Now 64 bit IEEE754 float allows 52 bits for mantissa, so I need to round the number to 52 bits.

$$ 1.\underbrace{1001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001}_{52 bits}100110... \times 2^{-4} $$

So I have to round to either:

smaller number (truncated)

$$ 1.1001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001 $$

larger number (original number plus 1)

$$ 1.1001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010 $$

Since the `53` bit is `1`, I'm rounding up to the larger number. So I have mantissa part ready. Then I'm calculating biased exponent (11 bits for the exponent):

$$ 2^{11-1} -1 = 1023\\
1023-4=1019\\
1019_{10} = 1111111011_2  $$

So the final representation should be:
$$ \underbrace{0}_{sign}\underbrace{01111111011}_{exponent}\underbrace{1001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010}_{mantissa} $$

Is this correct?

Comment: sorry, didn't understand what you meant

Comment: no problem, thanks anyways)

Comment: I think you meant $0.1_2$ in the second line, not $0.1_{10}$.

Comment: No, it's in base-10 system

Comment: This is strange, because $0.1$ in base $10$ is $0.1$. itself.

Comment: ah, I see, check now if it makes sense. I've replaced 10 with 2

Answer (score 1):

Short C code:

```
double x = 0.1;
long long n = *(long long*)&x;
printf("%llX",n);
```

Gives `3FB999999999999A`, which is equivalent to:

```
0011 1111 1011 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1010
```

For the record, due to the [strict aliasing rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing), I cannot recommend this programming method.

Comment: Well, it seems that I've done it right then)

Comment: @Maximus: Seems so :)

Comment: Just use std::memcpy or std::bitcast. This will have no problems with aliasing.